# Selecting distinct values based on relationship

Tags: postgresql, select, distinct, postgresql-9.2

## Context:

Given a table that stores user relationship information, a single record represents a unidirectional relationship i.e. *user_1* is following *user_2* when in the record column '***userid***' is user_1 and column '***relateduserid***' is user_2. If a second record exists where user column 'userid' is user_2 and column 'relateduserid' is user_1 then we consider these two 'friends' and the relationship is (logically) considered bidirectional.

**EDIT**: All user information is stored in a separate "user" table.

## Question:

I am looking to get all distinct userid's of unidirectional relationships (i.e. there's only one record where my userid and the person I am following's userid appear) where the relateduserid is **NOT** a given userid.

I have attempted several queries that don't return the correct results e.g. using distinct userid returns **all** the userids in the table.

```
select distinct userid from userRelTable where relateduserid <> 1234
```

Comment: You mentioned you only want unidirectional relationships. So, if the relationship is bi-directional, (from the user_1 user_2 example), do you want one record to show up (one record to represent the friendship) or neither record to show up?

Comment: I edited the question slightly to clarify that all user information is stored in a separate user table. It would make sense to get the userID's from there while using the userRelTable for comparisons. To answer your question, I would like to get the userID's of all users that are not in a uni-directional or bi-directional relationship with user_2 but who have an id in the user table.

Comment: Follow up question: Can the "user_1" value show up in more than one record in the userid field of the userRelTable?

Comment: Yes, the user_1 can show up more than once in the userid field of the useRelTable since they can be in a uni-directional relationship with other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two tables user and userRelTable, I populated the user table with six users, and I populated the userRelTable with six relationships.

```
ID  userid
-----------
1   user_1
2   user_2
3   user_3
4   user_4
5   user_5
6   user_6
```

```
ID  userid  relateduserid
-------------------------
1   user_1  user_2
2   user_2  user_1
3   user_2  user_3
4   user_3  user_1
5   user_4  user_6
6   user_5  user_6
```

Given the criteria, this query will give you all users that have neither a uni-directional or bi-directional relationship with 'user_2'

```
    select * from [user]
    where [user].userid
    not in
    (
        select userid from userRelTable
        where userRelTable.userid = 'user_2'
        or userRelTable.relateduserid = 'user_2'
    )
    and [user].userid 
    not in
    (
        select relateduserid from userRelTable
        where userRelTable.userid = 'user_2'
        or userRelTable.relateduserid = 'user_2'
    )
```

The result is the following table:

```
ID  userid
-----------
4   user_4
5   user_5
6   user_6
```

The only one in question is user_3. By definition, user_3 should not be in the result set because there is a uni-directional relationship with user_2 at ID #3.

Answer (score 1):

This query will select the unidirectional relationships, filtering out the bidirectional:

```
SELECT userid, relateduserid FROM userRelTable
 EXCEPT ALL
SELECT relateduserid, userid FROM userRelTable;
```

Using this as a baseline, you may pre-filter or post-filter the results depending on the case.

For instance, to get all the distinct `userid` that are in a unidirectional relationship, except those who follow or are followed by userid `1234`, this should work:

```
  SELECT distinct u.userid FROM
    (
      SELECT userid, relateduserid FROM userRelTable
        EXCEPT ALL
      SELECT relateduserid, userid FROM userRelTable
    ) u
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 from userRelTable r
           WHERE (r.userid=u.userid AND r.relateduserid=1234)
              OR (r.userid=1234 AND u.userid=r.relateduserid)
      );
```

Comment: Though I picked my answer, I'll run this too and see how it works for speed (on a DB of about 30 million entries)